# Are there traditional Orthodox websites that counter thetorah.com?

Tags: internet, pentateuch-chumash, machlokes, authorship, biblical-criticism

[thetorah.com](http://thetorah.com/) promotes arguments for the view that the Torah (and other books of Tanach) were written by multiple authors over a long period of time. They do this while still seeing themselves under the umbrella of Orthodox Judaism (Open Orthodoxy).

I've read that when this site came online two years ago, there were a lot of detractors. Could anyone point me to the articles arguing against thetorah.com, and are there any sites dedicated to arguing against each article on thetorah.com on an article by article basis?

Comment: FWIW, Open Orthodoxy agrees that Torah was written by Hakadosh Baruch Hu, as were some of the nevi'im, the remainder being authored by humans with ruach hakodesh.

Comment: Yes. I didn't mean to suggest otherwise.

Comment: As I recall, the book http://www.amazon.com/The-Pentateuch-Haftorahs-Translation-Commentary/dp/0900689218 has detailed arguments against the view that the Torah has multiple authors.

Comment: Not a website but [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Documentary-Hypothesis-Umberto-Cassuto/dp/9657052351/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1449078030&sr=8-4&keywords=cassuto) by R Umberto Cassuto disproves the documentary hypothesis. Since there is a Kindle version of it, it might qualify as an online source...

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of that book. Disprove is a bit of a strong word. Sad that there aren't more traditional resources online

Comment: This post: http://seforim.blogspot.com/2015/01/blog-post.html discuses a book: _Ad Hayom HaZeh_ on the topic by R. Amnon Bazak. However, I think he adopts rather liberal views.

Comment: Not a website, but [this book](http://www.kotar.co.il/KotarApp/Viewer.aspx?nBookID=103804665#8.1618.6.default) (partial paywall) contains a lot of articles from different people on the subject, and is one of the few whose authors are well aware of Bible criticism. Some of the authors also have articles on the internet (e.g. search Google for "Joshua Berman" in Hebrew or English - he's also been, incidentally, directly criticized on thetorah.com)

Answer (score 3):

In the comments above, I had previously recommended [R Umberto Cassuto's book](http://a.co/7xd4JY1). In the meantime I came across R Chaim Jachter's [Reason to believe](http://a.co/2LZTv0v) which has a page addressing biblical criticism. He cites two websites relevant for your search

- Online shiurim from R Amnon Bazak at [VBM](http://etzion.org.il/en/topics/fundamental-issues-study-tanakh)
- Online shiurim from R Menachem Leibtag (I think correct URL is now [tanach.org](http://www.tanach.org/))

[image]

Open Orthodoxy's position might have moved since the question was written, they have recently been judged quite critically by mainstream Orthodox movements, see e.g., [here](http://www.israelnationalnews.com/Articles/Article.aspx/20131), [here](http://www.jpost.com/Diaspora/Open-Orthodoxy-outside-bounds-of-tradition-says-European-rabbinical-group-434314) and [here](http://blogs.timesofisrael.com/closing-the-door-on-open-orthodoxy-why-the-orthodox-union-prohibited-female-clergy/).